# Weird cookie can't ve saved as global on postman

Tags: javascript, cookies, postman

I'm trying to save a cookie as variable using the following code:

```
var my_cookie = pm.cookies.get("cookie1");
pm.globals.set("gateway_token", my_cookie);
```

when I tried logging `my_cookie` I get `undefined` as response, a test domain with a test cookie was returning a positive response, is there any possibility that my domain was blocking this variable to be created?

is there any other solution for this case?

EDIT: I was doing more testing and I realise, what if this code is not retieving the cookie from interceptor? when I hit send on my domain there is nothing on the cookie tab (The one on the bottom of the screen, next to Body, headers and test results), I can only see them on the Cookie tab on the top right corner (next to SEND buttom).